# When trying to create a SSL connection with LWP::UserAgent, what do I use for realm?

Tags: security, perl, ssl, https

I've started a project to scrape my work's employee website to scrape the user's (in this case, mine) schedule and munge the data onto a google calendar.  I've decided to go with Perl with LWP.

The problem is this, when trying to set up SSL negotiations I don't know what do put for the 'realm'.

For example: (http://www.sciencemedianetwork.org/wiki/Form_submission_with_LWP,_https,_and_authentication)

```
# ... 
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;

$ua->protocols_allowed( [ 'http','https'] );
$ua->credentials('some.server:443',**'realm'**,'username','password');
# ...
```

I've looked at everything my browser can tell me and at a wireshark packet capture trying to find anything but to no avail.  I assume that second argument to credentials() isn't optional.

Where do I find the 'realm' I'm supposed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `credentials` are for the HTTP authentication protocol ([RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_authentication)).
The server can challenge the client to authenticate itself. This response contains a string called “realm” which tells the client for *what* authentication is required. This allows the same server under the same domain to request authentication for different things, e.g. in a content management system where there might be an “user password” and an “administrator password”, which would be two different realms.

In a browser, this realm would be displayed alongside the username and password box which allows the user to type in the correct password.

To discover the realm, navigate to a page which requires authentication and look for the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Note that HTTP authentication has become quite uncommon, with session cookies being used more often. To deal with such an authentication scheme, make sure that your `LWP::UserAgent` has an attached cookie storage, and then navigate through the login form before visiting your actual target page. Using `WWW::Mechanize` tends to make this a lot easier.

Comment: Very good, I was thinking it was part of the SSL Layer.  I was looking at WWW::Mechanize too and decided against it.  I'll definitely try it out.  Thank You!